# How to verify whether NTP auth is using SHA1 digest?

Tags: authentication, sha1, ntp

I have cross compiled NTP with crypto, for my embedded LINUX machine.
Now I want to verify sha1 authentication.
I have configured my LINUX machine as NTP server. This NTP comes with crypto enabled.

In my embedded LINUX machine, SHA1 is used as digest in ntp.keys and enabled auth.
I have shared trusted keys with both server and client.

I have captured NTP traffic when sync started from client.
I see that under NTP, key size is 160 bits, which means its using SHA1.

My question is, is there any other way using which I can double confirm that NTP is using SHA1. Like using some display commands where it displays what auth digest is it using?

thanks in advance and forgive for fat finger typo.

[NTP traffic capture from client using cross compiled NTP with sha1 auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpAFo.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the key (not key number but key that you have set on server, client) you can use some online tool to recalculate the SHA to see if it matches.

What you are looking for is SHA1(your key+your packet without auth(48bytes)) should match what you have captured (it would match the first 16 bytes, i think last 4 bytes are removed due to packet size considerations for NTP)